# PHP: How do I split an array at a gap in values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of integers that has a break (maybe even multiple breaks) in it, and I need to split the array where the break exists such that:

```
$input = (1,2,3,6,7,8,11,12,13)
$output[1] = (1,2,3)
$output[2] = (6,7,8)
$output[3] = (11,12,13)
```

I'm dealing with a rather large set of data (time), so memory optimization has been a sticking point for me ($i++ gets kinda hairy).

Thanks for your help!

---

More information:

I am starting with a large time range (strtotime/60 values for beginning and end), my original array therefore consists of however many minutes are in the time range in question. Since some people may sign up to cover only part of this time, I'm subtracting out the values that are already covered, leaving me with an array of times that need to be filled. I'm looking to parse those into multiple arrays (I really only need the min and max values, but I can isolate those easily) so that I can work with them to highlight the open times. Hopefully that's not too confusing - thank you to everyone who already replied!

Comment: What you mean by break ?

Comment: Where are these "breaks"? Trying to chunk them? Those are arrays? Maybe `$output = array_chunk($input, 3);` ?

Comment: Where are the breaks? And if it a very large array, better use numpy. Be more specific and we are pleased to help u.

Comment: The breaks aren't in any sort of predictable enough pattern to chunk them, unfortunately, although that's exactly what I'm trying to do, just with varying sizes. What I'm trying to do is subtract out time ranges from a larger time range, any of these could be several hours long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice question, here you go. This code will create a new sub array every time there is a break in sequence of numbers (as implied by your test case).

```
<?php
$input = array(1,2,3,6,7,8,11,12,13);
sort($input);

$i=0;
$output=array();
$previous=NULL;
foreach($input as $value)
{  
    if($value>$previous+1)
    {
      $i++;
    }
    $output[$i][]=$value;     
    $previous=$value;
}
print_r($output);
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/DDosXx7n)**

**[Another Fiddle with more data](http://codepad.org/3lHkI1N2)**

Comment: Its a nice question, if you had formatted it better and explained a little more you would have received a lot of up-votes. People here are very trigger happy and love to down-vote fast